# Symfony2 - upload multiple files using collection prototype, file shoud be in dependent table

Tags: forms, symfony, file-upload, doctrine, prototype

I have got an issue with uploading file via symfony form. Everything works fine when i have only one entity and want to upload file but when I use collection prototype to multi add more fields and have source and dependant tables everything goes wrong.

Source table Pro_profile
Dependant table Pro_education

I ve got form for Pro_profile and want to add some fields using prototype and as those fields are string, integer etc it works fine, but when i add to collection a File field and want to add to controller some code to get path, upload etc it doesn't work. I think the reason is i use controller for Pro_profile and want to load file to different entity, but i have no idea how to access this Pro_education entity.

Whole tutorials i found talk about uploading files when you ve got one entity, but no word about uploading to dependent table.

Could you help me with that?

Pro_profile.php

```
namespace My\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

    /**
     * Pro_profile
     *
     * @ORM\Table()
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\MainBundle\Entity\Pro_profileRepository")
     */
    class Pro_profile
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;
        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Pro_education", mappedBy="profile", cascade= {"persist"})
         */
         protected $educations;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
             $this->educations = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        }

       /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Add educations
         *
         * @param \My\MainBundle\Entity\Pro_education $educations
         * @return Pro_profile
         */
        public function addEducation(\My\MainBundle\Entity\Pro_education $educations)
        {
            $educations->setProfile($this); 
            $this->educations->add($educations);

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Remove educations
         *
         * @param \My\MainBundle\Entity\Pro_education $educations
         */
        public function removeEducation(\My\MainBundle\Entity\Pro_education $educations)
        {
            $this->educations->removeElement($educations);
        }

        /**
         * Get educations
         *
         * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
         */
        public function getEducations()
        {
            return $this->educations;
        }
```

Pro_education.php

```
namespace My\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Pro_education
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\MainBundle\Entity\Pro_educationRepository")
 */
class Pro_education
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=128, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=64, nullable=true)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=128, nullable=true)
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    public $file;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="verified", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $verified;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=128, nullable=true)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pro_profile", inversedBy="educations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="profile_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
     protected $profile;


    /**
     * Get city
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'uploads/documents';
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }

        // we use the original file name here but you should
        // sanitize it at least to avoid any security issues

        // move takes the target directory and then the target filename to move to
        $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->file->getClientOriginalName());

        // set the path property to the filename where you'ved saved the file
        $this->path = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();

        // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
        $this->file = null;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Pro_education
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Pro_education
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return Pro_education
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * Set verified
     *
     * @param boolean $verified
     * @return Pro_education
     */
    public function setVerified($verified)
    {
        $this->verified = $verified;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get verified
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getVerified()
    {
        return $this->verified;
    }

    /**
     * Set city
     *
     * @param string $city
     * @return Pro_education
     */
    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set profile
     *
     * @param \My\MainBundle\Entity\Pro_profile $profile
     * @return Pro_education
     */
    public function setProfile(\My\MainBundle\Entity\Pro_profile $profile)
    {
        $this->profile = $profile;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get profile
     *
     * @return \My\MainBundle\Entity\Pro_profile 
     */
    public function getProfile()
    {
        return $this->profile;
    }
}
```

Pro_profileEducationType.php

```
namespace My\MainBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class Pro_profileEducationType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('educations', 'collection', array('type' => new Pro_educationType(),
                                                  'allow_add' => true,
                                                  'by_reference' => false,
                                                  'allow_delete' => true,
                                                  'label' => false,
                                                  ))

    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'My\MainBundle\Entity\Pro_profile'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_mainbundle_pro_profile_education';
    }
}
```

Pro_educationType.php

```
namespace My\MainBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class Pro_educationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text', array(
                                        'attr' => array ('placeholder' => 'Nazwa szkoły/uczelni'), 
                                        'label' => false,                                                        
                                        ));
        $builder-> add('title', 'text', array(
                                        'attr' => array ('placeholder' => 'Uzyskany tytuł'), 
                                        'label' => false,                                                        
                                        ));
        $builder-> add('file', 'file', array(

                                        'label' => 'Skan dyplomu', 
                                        'multiple' => true,
                                        'data_class' => null,                                                       
                                        )) ;
        $builder-> add('city', 'text', array(
                                        'attr' => array ('placeholder' => 'Miasto'), 
                                        'label' => false,                                                        
                                        ));

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'My\MainBundle\Entity\Pro_education',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'pro_educations';
    }
}
```

RegistrationSpecialEducationController.php - at the end probably there is a problem because i try to use upload() function which is inside to Pro_education.php (dependant) no in main Pro_profile entity and there shows up an error

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "upload" of class
>   "My\MainBundle\Entity\Pro_profile".

```
namespace My\MainBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use My\MainBundle\Entity\Pro_profile;
use My\MainBundle\Entity\Pro_education;
use My\MainBundle\Form\Pro_profileEducationType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class RegistrationSpecialEducationController extends Controller
{ 
    /**
     * Creates a new Pro_profile entity.
     *
     * @Route("/create_education", name="pro_profile_create_education")
     * @Method("POST")
     * @Template("MyMainBundle:RegistrationSpecialEducation:education.html.twig")
     */ 
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
       $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser()->getId();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('MyMainBundle:Pro_profile')->findOneBy(array('user' => $user));


       // $educations = $entity-> getEducations();

        //$scan = $educations -> getScan();

        //foreach ($educations as $edu) {
//
        //    $tabela = $edu ->getScan();
       // }



        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);



            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

                $entity->getEducations() ->upload();

                $em->persist($entity);
                $em->flush();

                $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('RegisterSpecialEducation'));
            }



        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
           // 'edu' => $tabela,
        );
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to create a Pro_profile entity.
     *
     * @param Pro_profile $entity The entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createCreateForm(Pro_profile $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new Pro_profileEducationType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('pro_profile_create_education'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Zakończ rejestracje'));

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/register/special/education", name="RegisterSpecialEducation")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function educationAction()
    {
        $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser()->getId();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('MyMainBundle:Pro_profile')->findOneBy(array('user' => $user));

        $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }


}
```

maybe my problem is in miss understanding the issue, but I really tried to find a solution out by myself and I am stuck.

If you could help me with this one I would be greatful.